# How to add object search when defining custom options for maniphest in phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

I am trying to set a custom search field in maniphest by adding fileds in `maniphest.custom-field-definitions`. Full customization is below

```
{
  "mycompany:estimated-hours": {
    "name": "Estimated Hours",
    "type": "text",
    "caption": "Estimated number of hours this will take.",
    "required": true
  },
  "mycompany:deadline": {
    "name": "Deadline",
    "type": "date",
    "caption": "Deadline of the project"
  },
  "mycompany:actual-hours": {
    "name": "Actual Hours",
    "type": "text",
    "caption": "Actual number of hours this took."
  },
  "mycompany:company-jobs": {
    "name": "Work Type",
    "type": "select",
    "options": {
      "mycompany:engineer": "Engineer",
      "mycompany:designer": "Designer",
      "mycompany:qa": "Quality Assurance",
      "mycompany:other": "Non Technical"
    }
  },
  "mycompanyname:fieldname": {
    "name": "Blocked by task",
    "type": "users",
    "caption": "Add any dependency on other tasks",
    "required":false
  }
}
```

I am having problems setting search field for `Blocked by task` in phabricator. This field is supposed to search maniphest the way it does with `type="users"`

I had spent my whole day trying to achieve this functionality in many ways like

```
{
"mycompany:blocks-manifest": {
    "name": "Blocked By",
    "type": "text",
    "strings": {
        "search.default": "(ANY)"
    },
    "caption": "If there is any dependency, please specify",
    "options" :{
        "search.default": "(ANY)"
    }
  }
}
```

As well as

```
{
  "mycompany:blocks-manifest": {
    "name": "Blocked By",
    "type": "search",
    "strings": {
        "search.default": "(ANY)"
    },
    "caption": "If there is any dependency, please specify"
  }
}
```

And this way too

```
{
  "mycompany:blocks-manifest": {
    "name": "Blocked By",
    "type": "text",
    "strings": search.default,
    "caption": "If there is any dependency, please specify"
  }
}
```

If I summarize myself, I had reviewed the documentation in this regard from [Configuring Custom Fields](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/custom_fields/) in Phabricator documentation but no gain.

Any clue on how to fix or achieve the method of searching previous tasks in phabricator under `maniphest.custom-field-definations`?

Advise from any phabricator is highly encouraged like.

if I have to achieve this by [Adding New Classes](https://secure.phabricator.com/diviner/find/?book=phabcontrib&name=Adding_New_Classes&type=article&jump=1), please suggest how to for this.

Comment: There is natively a "Blocked by" field in Maniphest, why are you using custom fields?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just discovered. Anyways, can you please put an answer so I can mark as accepted and close the question?

Between any idea on linking one task with another task using custom field would be helpful too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the native "Blocked By" or "Blocks" fields that come with Maniphest by default. This is the simplest option.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the process. I was expecting this to be a custom option instead of a core feature.